# Adding mock object into sqlalchemy collection raises exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, mocking, python-mock

I am writing a unit test for SQLAlchemy model class with one-to-many relationship but am not able to add a mocked object into the collection.

Classes under test:

```
class PCLRun(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pcl_runs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    files = relationship("PCLOutputFile", backref='pcl_run')

class PCLOutputFile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pcl_output_files'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    pcl_run_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('pcl_runs.id'))
```

Test code:

```
class PCLRunTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        file_mock = mock.Mock()
        pcl_run = PCLRun()
        pcl_run.files.append(file_mock)
        ...
```

Appending the mock object raises an exception:

```
TypeError: 'Mock' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Is there any way to unit test the class containing the relationship by adding mocks into it while keeping the collection behave like a simple list?

I'm using mock 1.0.1 and sqlalchemy 0.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think think the issue is that the `PCLRun` instance is expecting an instance of the `PCLOutputFile` class as an argument to the `append` method. Your `Mock` instance has none of the same attributes so it raises an error when it tries the `__getitem__` method.

You could try take advantage of Python use of duck-typing to create a `Mock` object with all the attributes of a `PCLOutputFile` file but that might prove difficult depending on how much inherited metadata beyond the column values the query needs..

Alternately, you could define setup/teardown methods/fixtures which would create *real* instance of the `PCLOutputFile` class in your test table. The nosetest module provides [tools](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-classes) to for this type of testing pattern.